# Looking for help in Java Code Architecture

Tags: java, performance, class, architecture, chess

Hey Currently I am developing a chess game but have gone to the mistake of putting all my java code in one java file

I need help cutting up my code into more manageable chucks

I was hoping someone could show me how to take out all the piece movements and put them in a separate file which then links back in to the main file ?

I have tried myself but i end up just breaking the game

Here is the full messy java file currently I only have some of the pieces coded up so i thought i would not go further without solving the terrible architecture here

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessProject extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;

    public ChessProject() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  Use a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            chessBoard.add(square);

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0) {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray);
            } else {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white);
            }
        }

        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhitePawn.png"));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKing.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);
        for (int i = 48; i < 56; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackPawn.png"));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKing.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackQueen.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }

    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y) {
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Check if a piece is a Black piece.
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("Black")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    //Check if a piece is a White piece.

    private Boolean checkBlackOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("White")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return;
        }

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX() / 75);
        startY = (e.getY() / 75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }
        chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Boolean success = false;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
        String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
        Boolean validMove = false;

//Pawn Moves
//White Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")) {
            if (startY == 1) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 6) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) {
                                if (startY == 6) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
//Black Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("BlackPawn")) {
            if (startY == 6) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 1) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -1) {
                                if (startY == 2) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Pawn Moves
        //Knight Moves
        //White Knight Code
        else if (pieceName.contains("WhiteKnight")) {

            // next we need to get the new coordinates for where the piece is being dropped.
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;

            // We need to make sure that the piece is being put back on the board...if its not being on
            // the board why would we want to check anything else!
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {

                if (((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY - 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY - 1))) {
                    validMove = true;

                    if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                        if (pieceName.contains("White")) {
                            if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        } //Black Knight Code
        else if (pieceName.contains("BlackKnight")) {

                    // next we need to get the new coordinates for where the piece is being dropped.
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;

                    // We need to make sure that the piece is being put back on the board...if its not being on
                    // the board why would we want to check anything else!
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                if (((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY - 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY - 1))) {
                    validMove = true;

                    if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                        if (pieceName.contains("Black")) {
                            if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Knight Code
        //Bishop Code
        //White Bishup
        else if (pieceName.contains("WhiteBishup")) {
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;
            boolean inTheWay = false;
            int distance = Math.abs(startX - newX);
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                validMove = true;
                if (Math.abs(startX - newX) == Math.abs(startY - newY)) {
                    if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (inTheWay) {
                        validMove = false;
                    } else {
                        if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if (pieceName.contains("White")) {
                                if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        } //Black Bishup
        else if (pieceName.contains("BlackBishup")) {
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;
            boolean inTheWay = false;
            int distance = Math.abs(startX - newX);
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                validMove = true;
                if (Math.abs(startX - newX) == Math.abs(startY - newY)) {
                    if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (inTheWay) {
                        validMove = false;
                    } else {
                        if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if (pieceName.contains("Black")) {
                                if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Bishup Code


//Changes to new pawn Piece and Validates Move

    if(!validMove){
        int location=0;
        if(startY ==0){
            location = startX;
        }
        else{
            location  = (startY*8)+startX;
        }
        String pieceLocation = pieceName+".png";
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(pieceLocation) );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }
    else{
        if(success){

            if (c instanceof JLabel){
                Container parent = c.getParent();
                parent.remove(0);

                String promoteTo;
                do {
                    promoteTo = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Promote Pawn to :", "Pawn Promotion",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                        new String[]{"Queen", "Bishup", "Knight", "Rook"}, "Queen");
                } while (promoteTo == null);
                String newPiece = null;
                int location = 0;
                if (pieceName.contains("White"))
                {
                    location = 56 + (e.getX()/75);
                    newPiece = "White"+promoteTo;
                }
                else
                {
                    location =  (e.getX()/75);
                    newPiece = "Black"+promoteTo;
                }

                pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(newPiece+".png") );
                parent = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                parent.add(pieces);
                validate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        else{
            if (c instanceof JLabel){
                Container parent = c.getParent();
                parent.remove(0);
                parent.add( chessPiece );
            }
            else {
                Container parent = (Container)c;
                parent.add( chessPiece );
            }
            chessPiece.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ChessProject();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks gain for any help you can provide me

Comment: This is a very broad question and therefore not really in the scope of StackOverflow. Generally for any non-trivial java program you need to design your application before you write it. For example this is a prime candidate for an application with a GameBoard class and a ChessPiece class (amongst others)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for advice on refactoring functioning code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after requires refactoring of your code. I suggest you write some tests to verify your working logic before you start refactoring. Once you think you have enough coverage of your code, start refactoring small pieces of code at a time (only small pieces of code at a time). After every change you make, run your tests to see if you have broken anything. Repeat the process of making small changes and running tests until you are satisfied.